# Zinc, weight loss and testosterone

Tags: testosterone, zinc, growth-hormones

What would be the effect of adding zinc rich diet on a teenager's testosterone levels who is already at the low end? Minimum and maximum increase in the levels? Also, is it necessary to add the zinc supplements?